# Domain Driven Design for Rails App: Implementing a service in a basic example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, component-based

Two Models: An `Owner` and a `Dog`:

**`owner.rb`**

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dog
end
```

**`dog.rb`**

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner
end
```

And here is the schema:

**`schema.rb`**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 123) do

  create_table "dogs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "energy"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "dogs", ["owner_id"], name: "index_dogs_on_owner_id"

  create_table "owners", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "energy"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Pretty simple setup.

I want an `owner` to take his `dog` for a walk.  When the walk ends, the owner's energy will drop by 5, AND the dog's energy will drop by 20.

Clearly this `walk_the_dog` action/method, wherever it is going to live, is effecting two objects: an `owner` object and a `dog` object (and of course this dog object happens to be associated to this owner).

I don't know where to put this code.  I know I *could* simply create an action within the **`owners_controller.rb`**, but that seems like a bad idea.  It would look something like this:

**`owners_controller.rb`**

```
class OwnersController < ApplicationController
    def walk_the_dog
        @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
        @owner.energy -= 5
        @owner.dog.energy -= 20   # this line in particular seems like bad OO design
        @owner.save
        @owner.dog.save
    end
    ...
 end
```

As I understand it, objects should only change state for themselves and shouldn't change the state of other objects.  So this appears to be a bad idea because within the owner controller we are changing the state of not just the `owner` object, but the associated `dog` object as well.

I have read about services.  It seems like `walk_the_dog` is an excellent case for a service, because services, as I understand it, allow interactions between objects and state changes for multiple objects.  I just don't know how to do it/implement it.

Should there be a service object called `walk_the_dog`?  Should their just be a file within a services directory with a bunch of service methods -- one of which is called `walk_the_dog` and the **`owners_controller.rb`** simply utilizes this method in it's controller?  I don't know what the next step is.

**Note**: I can see someone saying "who cares if this breaks OO design.  Just do it and if it works, it works."  Unfortunately this is not an option.  The application I am working on now followed that mindset.  The application grew very large, and now maintaining it is very difficult.  I want to get this situation down for the major redesign of the app.

Comment: I'd use a walk the dog service. But following OOP, it couldnt do stuff like `@owner.energy -= 5` you;d have to implement a `decrement_energy` method

Comment: @apneadiving any tips or suggested resources on how to implement services in a rails app? Do I have the concept of a service in a rails app correct?

Comment: http://slides.com/apneadiving/service-objects-waterfall-rails/live#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the few things that I would do if I were to refactor this code:

Writing numbers in your code is a bad thing, either you have defined them as constants like `ENERGY_PER_WALK_FOR_DOG = 20` or a better way is to define a field in the table of `Dog` model. This way, it will be much better to manage and assign those values.

```
add_column :dogs, energy_per_walk, :integer, default: 20
add_column :owners, energy_per_walk, :integer, default: 5
```

I'd create a method in `ApplicationController` class:

```
def walk(resources = [])
  resources.each do |resource|
    resource.lose_walk_energy # you can refine it more!
  end
end
```

In the folder, **app/models/concerns**, I would write the following module:

```
module Walkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern


  # subtract energy_per_walk form the energy saved in db
  def lose_walk_energy
    self.energy -= self.energy_per_walk
    save
  end

end
```

And now, your method reduces to the following method:

```
def walk_the_dog
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  walk([@owner, @owner.dog])
end
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response.  Follow up question: If the application scales then one couldn't continue putting methods in ApplicationController.  Otherwise there could be dozens, or even a hundred methods in there!  Where would you put those methods then when the application scales?  So for your refactoring above: where would you put the method: walk when ApplicationController becomes too bloated?

Comment: We define those methods in `ApplicationController` that are shared between two or more controllers. If you so a lot of code shared between two controllers, then it means you need to make a new controller, and make those two controllers to inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this should be a method in the Owner model. You also need to do both operations in one transaction, to ensure, that both models have been updated.

```
class Owner
  has_one :dog

  def walk_the_dog
    return false if dog.nil?

    transaction do
      decrement!(:energy, 5)
      dog.decrement!(:energy, 20)
    end
  end
end
```